# converting PWSTR variable to upper case in vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

how i can convert `PWSTR` variable to uppercase in `vc++`. I googled but didn't get the code sample.

**EDITED**

What i want to do with `PWSTR` variable is, a method's return type is `PWSTR`. I have to check whether the returned value is equal to string `"Y"`. so whatever comes from return I am trying to UPPER its case then checking.

One more thing I want to know, how to use `PWSTR` var in `if()` condition checking.

**thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`_tcsupr_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sae941fh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and friends which should get you in the right direction.

**EDIT:**

Following on from your edit, you don't need to worry about converting to upper case for you to then do the comparison -- you can instead call the case insensitive string comparison function, [`_tcsicmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (or its friends if you're not compiling for Unicode) - there is example code if you follow the link, which also explains the importance of having set the correct locale to give the results you're expecting.

Comment: That should be _wcsupr().  Can't make a PWSTR secure without knowing a lot more.

Comment: @Hans hence why I used the term in inverted commas. I appreciate I mentioned the `TCHAR` version intentionally, but the destination of the link mentions al of the variants, and also which version will be called based on whether UNICODE has been defined, etc.

Comment: I am new in vc++ and dunno how to use this method. Can u give me sample.

Answer (score 1):

There you are - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sch3dy08%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: That's the deprecated version -- see my answer for the "more secure" versions